# Problemas de codificación en html en tildes y eñes

Tags: php

He diseñado una web con Dreamweaver basada en una plantilla bootstrap. EL problema está en el formulario de contacto. Me llegan al correo un día más tarde y con errores de tildes y ñ cuando creo que lo tengo bien.

Hay algún error en el código, o podría ser problema de configuración en mi servidor? Mi control Panel utiliza Versión de Apache 2.2.31 y Versión PHP 5.2.17

html:

```html
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
 <div id="contact-form-section">
<div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
<form id="contact-form" class="contact" name="contact-form" method="post" action="contacto.php">    
 <div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control name-field" required="required" placeholder="Nombre"></div>
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control mail-field" required="required" placeholder="Email"></div>
<div class="form-group">           
<textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea></div> 
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</div>
<label for="nospam" class="escondido">¡Si ves esto, no llenes el siguiente campo!</label>
<input name="nospam" class="escondido" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

el php:

```
 <?php
   header("Content-type: text/html;charset=\"utf-8\"");
    $error = ""; $mensajeExito = "";

     if ($_POST) {
      if ($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST["email"], 
        FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $error .= "E-mail no válido.<br>";   
    }
     if ($error != "") {
        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><b>Se generó un error:</b></p>' . $error . '</div>';
    } 



    else {
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $mail = $_POST['email'];
        $mensajeC = $_POST['mensaje'];

        $header = 'From: ' . $mail . " \r\n";
        $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
        $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

        $mensaje = "Este mensaje fue enviado por " . $nombre . ",\r\n";
        $mensaje .= "Su e-mail es: " . $mail . " \r\n";
        $mensaje .= "Mensaje: " . $mensajeC . " \r\n";
        $mensaje .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y', time());

        $para = 'info@dbolaonline.com';
        $asunto = 'Mensaje de mi sitio web';

        if (mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $header)) {
            $mensajeExito = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Mensaje enviado con éxito :)</div>';    
        } else {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>Mensaje sin enviar :(</div>';  
        } 
    }  
}
?>

 <?php

   if ($_POST['nospam'] != ""){
   // Es un SPAMbot
    exit();

    } else {
     // Es un usuario real, proceder a enviar el formulario.

    }
 ?>
```

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
       alert("Su mensaje se ha enviado correctamente. Responderemos lo 
      antes posible.");
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema radica en la forma en que se codifican los carácteres especiales como la ñ o la tilde.

Primero asegurate de que en el header de tu html se indica que la web está codificada en utf8:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

en último lugar, elimina la decodificación de utf8 en php, cambia esto:

```
utf8_decode($mensaje)
```

por esto:

```
$mensaje
```

Con ello consigues que a tu correo te llegue el texto codificado en utf8 de forma correcta.

Comment: Gracias. En el hmtl sí lo tengo codificado así.